# Example of composition of two normal field extensions which is not normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

If $F\supset E$ and $E\supset k$ are normal extensions. I want a counter-example where $F\supset k$ is not normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For seeing Normal extension of a Normal extension is Not Normal...

I feel it would be good choice to see that For a group $G$ and $H\leq K\leq G$ :

$H\unlhd K$ and $K\unlhd G$ but $H\ntrianglelefteq G$

Once you know such a chain of subgroups  then,  It would be obvious to get an example of Corresponding fields(Fixed fields)

One Basic exmple of such extension is  :

> $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$

Comment: Thank you for accepting :D

Answer (score 4):

A sure way to create a field extension is by adjoining roots. What kind of root can we adjoin to ensure normality always? The most obvious answer: square roots. What's a common field which isn't closed under square roots? Let's just pick $\Bbb Q$. Can you form a tower $A/B/\Bbb Q$ where both extensions are obtained by adjoining a square root, but $A/\Bbb Q$ is not normal? Biquadratic $A$ won't cut it (since then it'd be normal). Taking the square root of something in $B=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{b})$ will generally look like $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$; is there anyway we can make this simpler-looking? What's the simplest type of quadratic surd? Easy: just let $a=0$. Now what do we have?

Comment: Will this work $Q(2^{1/4})/Q(\sqrt{2})/Q$?

Comment: @Susobhan Do you have thoughts on that?

Comment: $Q(\sqrt 2)/Q$ and $Q(2^{1/4})/Q(\sqrt{2})$ normal is clear. $Q(2^{1/4})/Q$ is not normal because two roots of the polynomial $x^4-2$ belongs to $Q(2^{1/4})$ but not the other two.

Comment: Right. ${}{}{}$