# Find a counterexample to the statement "If $K\subset M\subset L$ are fields and $L$ is normal over $K$, then $M$ normal over $K$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I want to find a counter-example of three fields $K$, $M$, and $L$ where the following statement does not hold:

> If $K \subset M \subset L$ and $L$ is normal over $K$, then $M$ is normal over $K$.

I started with $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and think it could work with $M=\mathbb{Q}(A)$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(A,B)$  where $A$ and $B$ are some radicals. I haven't really gotten anywhere with this.

Comment: Do you know any example of $K\subset M$ that is not a normal extension?  Do you know what the normal closure of a field extension is?

Comment: $K=\Bbb Q$, $M=K(\sqrt[3]2)$, $L=M(\omega)$ where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

Comment: @Lubin would it be ok if you explain the reasoning behind this? Does it involve finding polynomials that act as splitting fields? Thank you :)

Comment: Perhaps. The big field $L$ is the splitting field of $X^3-2$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: ok got it... and M does not provide a splitting field over Q, since Q does not contain radicals?

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question I will try to explain Lubin's example which is probably the most intuitive one.

Let $K:= \mathbb{Q}$ and $M := \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

It is easy to see that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \vert \mathbb{Q}$ is not normal since $\sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is a root of $f(X):=X^3-2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ but $f(X)$ does not split into linear factors over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ because $f(\sqrt[3]{2} e^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/3})=f(\sqrt[3]{2} e^{4 \pi \mathrm{i}/3}) = 0$ and $\sqrt[3]{2} e^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/3}, \sqrt[3]{2} e^{4 \pi \mathrm{i}/3} \notin \mathbb{R} \supset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Now let $L:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},e^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/3})$. One can easily check that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},e^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/3})$ is the splitting field of $f(X)$ und thus $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},e^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/3}) \vert \mathbb{Q}$ is normal.

Now we are done since we found $L \subset M \subset K$ with $L \vert K$ normal and $ M \vert K$ not normal.