# Does $K/E$ and $E/F$ being normal mean $K/F$ is normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $F\subset E \subset K$ be fields. Suppose that $K/E$ and $E/F$ are normal. Is $K/F$ also normal?

I feel that this statement is not true in general but I cannot find a counter-example. Any thought?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is indeed not true. Take for example $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$, $E = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $F = \mathbb Q$. Then $[K:E] = [E:F] = 2$, so that $K/E$ and $E/F$ are normal. But $K/F$ is not normal, since $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is conjugate to $i\sqrt[4]{2}$ (both are roots of the irreducible polynomial $X^4-2\in \mathbb Q[X]$) but $i\sqrt[4]2$ does not lie in $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)$.