# If $F\subseteq L\subseteq K$ are fields with $K/L$ and $L/F$ Galois, then $K/F$ is Galois?.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

**If $F\subseteq L\subseteq K$ are fields with $K/L$ and $L/F$ Galois, then $K/F$ is Galois?.**

My intuition tells me that this is not true, but I can not find a counterexample, could someone give me one please? Thank you.

Comment: Both normal and separable are transitive

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Normality is not transitive.  In the same way that normality is not transitive for subgroups.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888827/is-normal-extension-of-normal-extension-always-normal

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not Galois. @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: @Quasicoherent About the converse, if a field $F$ is such that $K/L,  L/F$ Galois implies $K/F$ Galois. Does it mean every finite extensions of $F$ are Galois ? (example $F = \mathbf{F}_q$)

Comment: @reuns I don't know the answer to your question, but you may be able to cook up a counterexample by taking $F = \mathbb{F}_p(t)$ (the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{F}_p$).  Not every extension is Galois because there are inseparable extensions, but I'm not sure it satisfies the condition $K/L, L/F$ Galois $\implies K/F$ Galois.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that if an extension $E/F$ is separable with $[E:F]=2$, then $E/F$ is also normal, hence is Galois. So try to find a non-Galois degree $4$ extension $K$ of $F=\mathbb{Q}$ which contains a subfield $L$ with $[L:F]=2$.